# HTML Json parsing strings

Tags: javascript, json, html

I am using html and JSON.  What I am doing is creating levels for a game in JSON and parsing information in javascript.

I have no problem doing this when the information is an integer.  I will simply right the following for example:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < curNode.options.length; i ++) {
        var x = parseInt(curNode.options[i].x);
        var y = parseInt(curNode.options[i].y);
        //set the positions
        var choice = new Choice(scene);
        choice.setPosition(x, y);
   }
```

and so forth.  I can do this with width, height etc but I am not sure how to do this when simply dealing with a string.

Comment: `if(x == 'somestring'){ //code here }`

Comment: Number() or parseFloat() would be better than parseInt() in this case

Comment: @dandavis there is no time I would ever use a float

Comment: no problem. good luck with the game

Comment: Why do you need to call `parseInt` on something that's already an integer?

Answer (score 0):

You can do type casting easily as follows:

```
var avariable = 3; var astring = avariable + ''; var anotherstring = new String(avariable);
```